# Unable to call objects methods in django ''function' object has no attribute 'objects'"

Tags: python, django

Im trying to display some objects from django. When I use the administrator my objects are created but when I try to display it is impossible.

I tryed to make a render but when I initialize the screen never is called, then i tryed to make it with a GET button, now the function is called but when arrives to alumnos = Alumno.objects.all() throws 
'function' object has no attribute 'objects'.

models.py

```
class Alumno(models.Model):
    dni = models.CharField(max_length=9,primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    apellido1 = models.CharField('Primer apellido',max_length=50)
    apellido2 = models.CharField('Segundo apellido',max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField("Correo electronico",null=True)
    repetidor = models.BooleanField()
    curs = models.ManyToManyField(Curso, blank=True, related_name="Historico_de_cursos")
    Nivel = models.ManyToManyField('Nivel', through = 'Completado',through_fields=('Alumno','Nivel'))
    Practica = models.ManyToManyField('Practica', through = 'Nota',through_fields=('Alumno','Practica'))
    Curso = models.ManyToManyField('Curso',through = 'Curso_alumno',through_fields=('Alumno','Curso'))

objects = models.Manager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.dni

class Meta:
    db_table = "Alumno"
    verbose_name = 'Alumno'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Alumnos'
    unique_together = ("nombre", "apellido1", "apellido2")
```

view.py

```
def mostrar_alumnos(request):
    alumnos = Alumno.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'mostrar_alumnos.html', {'alumnos': alumnos}
```

mostrar_alumnos.html

```
{% if alumnos %}
    <ul>
    {% for alumno in alumnos %}
    <td>{{ alumno.dni }}</td>
    <td>{{ alumno.nombre }}</td>
    <td>{{ alumno.apellido1 }}</td>
    <td>
     <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{% url 'actualizar_alumno' alumno.dni %}"> Editar</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'eliminar_alumno' alumno.dni %}"> Esborrar</a> </td>
{% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No hay alumnos disponibles.</p>
{% endif %}
```

url.py

```
url(r'^mostrar_alumnos/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='mostrar_alumnos.html'),name='mostrar_alumnos'),
url(r'^mostrar_alumnos/$', views.mostrar_alumnos,name='mostrar_alumnos'),
url(r'^mostrar_alumnos2/$', views.mostrar_alumnos2,name='mostrar_alumnos2')
```

Comment: Did you by any change defined a function `Alumno` in your `views.py`? It looks llike you have "overwritten" the reference to that model. You need to check to what `Alumno` is refering, it is likely that there is a view in your `views.py` with the same name, or that you imported something else with that name.

Comment: yes I did that, I will check it

Comment: please do not give functions a name that starts with an uppercase, it is against PEP-8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, and [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350601/unable-to-call-objects-methods-in-django-function-object-has-no-attribute-ob?noredirect=1#comment99306254_56350601), you have constructed a view function with the name `Alumno`, as in:

```
# app/views.py

from app.models import Alumno

def Alumno(request):
    # ...
    pass

def mostrar_alumnos(request):
    alumnos = Alumno.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'mostrar_alumnos.html', {'Alumno': alumnos})
```

This means that if you write `Alumno.objects`, you are referring to the `Alumno` *function*, even if you imported the model, since you simply have set the `Alumno` identifier to that function when you defined it.

The simplest way to solve this is to rename your `Alumno` view to `alumno`, which is, according to [**PEP-8**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) the recommended way to name your function. In that case `Alumno` will thus refer to your imported model.

```
# app/views.py

from app.models import Alumno

def alumno(request):
    # ...
    pass

def mostrar_alumnos(request):
    alumnos = Alumno.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'mostrar_alumnos.html', {'alumnos': alumnos})
```

The name of the template variable probably should be `'alumnos'` instead of `Alumno`, in your template you can then render this with:

```
{% if alumnos %}
<ul>

    {% for alumno in alumnos %}
        <td>{{ Alumno.dni }}</td>
        <td>{{ Alumno.nombre }}</td>
        <td>{{ Alumno.apellido1 }}</td>
        <td>
         <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{% url 'actualizar_alumno' alumno.dni %}"> Editar</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'eliminar_alumno' alumno.dni %}"> Esborrar</a> </td>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Note that you do not have to define an `objects = models.Manager()` in your models. If you do not specify another manager, Django will automatically add a manager named `objects` to it.

Comment: thank you, this was one of my problems but still not displaying the list, I'm printing the list and is full but the html seems not affected.

Really sorry for disturbing

Comment: Your `for` loop in the template should be `{% for alumno in Alumnos %}`, although again here naming might be improved.

Comment: seems not working don't know why, I tryed with a button with GET method and withouth, the html is entering in the function but is not displaying anything

Comment: @Victor: did you change the context to `{'alumnos': alumnos}`, so renamed it to `'alumnos'` like the edit said?

Comment: @Victor: of course you should also rename it in `{% if alumnos %}`.

Comment: i updated with the code in the OP views and html but as I see is the same

Comment: @Victor: are there any `Alumo` objects in your database?

Comment: yes I have a script to populate and i have like 100, the html get stuck in the first if

Comment: @Victor: I've tested this locally, and it seems to work, so perhaps something else in the template is blocking that part from rendering.

Comment: Yes, in the main post you can see the code and I changed everything with your names

Comment: Now it works, sorry for the disturb, the mistake was I got tons of error codes for try to solve this problem, thank you for your time, I was like 6 hours looking for the error.